# delete half transparent pixels in image

Tags: transparency, png, color-conversion

I need to convert a 16bit png into an 8bit png for size reduction.
Problem are the half transparent pixels that will generate a white border around my content when converting to 8bit.
I just want to delete all pixels that are somewhere between 0 and 100% visible.
How would I do it?

Tools available are Photoshop and Gimp (both newest versions).

Here is an example image:

[image]

Comment: Are you throwing away the transparency on purpose? 8-bit PNGs also allow it.

Comment: The PNG8 format doesn't support multiple levels of transparency. It only has either totally opaque, or totally transparent pixels, no semi-transparency!  PNG8 is a bit like a GIF, which also suffers from the same problem.

Comment: @BillyKerr: you are confusing it with GIF transparency. 8-bit *palette* also supports transparency which (1) can have another value than 100% and (2) can have more palette entries, each with a different transparency.

Comment: Is the original image only one layer? Or do you have a mask which could be edited?

Comment: I only have the original 16bit png.

Comment: @usr2564301 - nope. 8bit PNGs are indexed colour, just like GIFs.

Comment: I found this thread how get these pixels into a layer mask in photoshop. and it seems to work (but not 100% sure). But I fail to find a way to actually delete them smoothly. -
 https://forums.adobe.com/thread/739988​

Comment: @BillyKerr: Don't let the bad support in Photoshop (for example) confuse you! [The official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#11tRNS) does not contain such a restriction **at all**: "For [indexed-colour], alpha is a series of values [...] Each entry indicates that the corresponding palette index has the specified alpha. [..] [A] tRNS chunk may contain fewer values than there are palette entries; the remaining values are assumed to be 255. When only palette index 0 need be made transparent, only a one-byte tRNS is required ..." (paraphrased, but do read the full text)

Comment: @usr2564301 - "bad support" - perhaps, but just try getting Photoshop to output semi-transparency in a PNG8.  It can't do it. It simply converts to Indexed colour.  What software do you suggest?

Comment: @BillyKerr: just try opening a bog standard PNG with alpha in Photoshop - it can't even do that properly . But, no, unfortunately I don't have a good alternative suggestion. I've never used GIMP; it may do better. For low-level PNG processing I usually write my own software.

Comment: @usr2564301 I use GIMP too, you have to convert to Indexed mode to ouput a PNG8.  Perhaps you have discovered a niche market for your software!

Comment: @BillyKerr actually  usr2564301 is right. However neither photoshop nor gimp support it. But all browser vendors do, if you try to open one of these pngs in Photoshop it will just fail spectacularly. And yes there are lots of free web compression tools that allow you to do this. And also many do some lossy compression thats almost invisible to human eye but much easier on the compression scheme.

Comment: @joojaa If there's a web tool that allows this, then perhaps you should add one of these as an answer.  It might help the OP avoid having to delete the semi transparent pixels altogether.

Comment: If the OP can add a sample image to the question, I could take a look at writing up some script to handle this.

Comment: Unfortunately that sample image either already *is* 8 bit RGBA, or my browser (checked Safari and Firefox) or imgur.com "helpfully" converts it ...

Comment: It must have been converted, but I just found out that Photoshop can actually safe 8bit with semi transparent pixels.

Comment: Sorry I meant "without semi transparent pixels". Also I confirmed imgur converts the image and just removes all the half transparent pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save without semi-transparent pixels as white pixels in Photoshop go to "Export for web" then select PNG 8bit.
Check "Transparency" and select "none" as "Matte" color.
For me this just removes the semi-transparent pixels alltogether.

Answer (score 9):

- In the *Layers* panel, `Ctrl+click` (or, if on mac `Cmd+click`) the layer thumbnail to turn its transparency into a selection.
- Use `Select > Edit in Quick Mask Mode` to enter *Quick Mask Mode*.
- Use `Image > Adjustments > Threshold` and set the *Threshold* to 255, to remove all transparent pixels.
- Push `Ctrl+i` (or if on mac `Cmd + i`) to inverse the mask.
- Exit *Quick Mask Mode* with `Select > Edit in Quick Mask Mode`.
- Make sure the layer is selected and press `Delete` to remove the transparent pixels.

This could be turned into an action.

Comment: So I tried and this works, but actually I don't need it as PS can save without semi transparent pixels.

Comment: @DarsVaeda, I thought you already tried that, but that it gave your image a white outline.

Comment: yes I tried but got the white outline. but I found an option to drop the transparent pixels now.